# CSS img causing trouble

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've created a very simple webpage, a header, a few content and a footer.

Here's the css:

```
.Footer{
  background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 398px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer img{
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer #About{
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and the HTML :

```
<div class="Footer">
    <img id="ceinture" src="medias/pictures/ceinture.jpg">

    <div id="About">
      Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. 
      ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, 
      et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut 
      satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.
    </div>
</div>
```

### The problem:

The footer is not at the bottom of the browser, but with a 3 or 4 pixels margin like so :

[image: issue screen shot]

If I remove the image (which is the grey part on the left) I get rid of the bottom margin, no way to remove it otherwise...

You can consult it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qe5Jg/1/) but the preview window must be larger than `768px` (due to CSS3 media queries)

Comment: And how high is your image ? Would it be possible to replace it with background-color or is it part of the content at some point ?

Comment: @Bartdude my image is 386px height, and is essential...

Comment: why are you doing inline-block to display your footer?

Comment: The text inside the `#about` should also be wrapped in an appropriate tag...probably a `<p>`. A JSFiddle would probably help.

Comment: Downvote without comment? come on.

Comment: How do you know who downvoted? BTW...is wasn't me.

Comment: @chawk because I've been told to do so, that's not the best answer... but that's why

Comment: @Paulie_D I changed it, not getting better. I don't know you did it, just saying that if I deserve a down-vote, I should know why :)

Comment: can you use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Indeed...we need to see the full HTML & CSS.

Comment: @Samoth > chawk is true about this, not needed. Also, you could use an `overflow:hidden` on this footer block that would probably solve the problem, but another issue may also be the carriage return characters between the image tag and the div tag... would be worth trying to stick those tags together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some advice.  You should find a layout you like by changing the sizes and things.  It's good idea to layout parent elements in a relative position, then display most items inside this container with absolute positioning.  the combination of the two positions will take you far with web development.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>    
<body>
    <div style="width: 960px; background-color: blue; min-height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">


    </div>

    <div style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; background-color: red; width: 960px; height: 200px">
    This is your footer, anything in your footer should be absolute positioned. 
    <div style="position: absolute; left:0; bottom:0;">
    I'm sitting on the left of the footer at the bottom. 
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The code makes no sense so that is why I gave my advice.  it's really difficult to say what the problem is with what you have.  It's not proper html/css.  I'm not even really sure what you're trying to do.  You can try to set margin: 0 and padding:0 on your image.

Comment: well, run the rendering on the original code, scroll down and keep in mind the space between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the rendering window then remove the image and compare the new space

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example, just **copy** and **paste**.

**html**

```
<div class="Footer">

<img id="ceinture" src="medias/pictures/ceinture.jpg">
    <div id="About">
      Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. 
      ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, 
      et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut 
      satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
       *{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.Footer{
  background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 398px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer img{
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer #About{
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't and even screw some other things :(

Comment: It's impossible,I have tested it again, it works.Do you write html,head,body etc.?

Comment: Well, it works if your page have no content, try to add a div of 2000px high and you'll see my point

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
    <div id="About">
    <img id="ceinture" src="medias/pictures/ceinture.jpg">
      Unde Rufinus ea tempestate praefectus praetorio ad discrimen trusus est ultimum. 
      ire enim ipse compellebatur ad militem, quem exagitabat inopia simul et feritas, 
      et alioqui coalito more in ordinarias dignitates asperum semper et saevum, ut 
      satisfaceret atque monstraret, quam ob causam annonae convectio sit impedita.
    </div>
</div>
```

**and css**

```
   *{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.Footer{
  background-color: rgb(238,238,238);

  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2000px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer img{
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Footer #About{
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;bottom: 0;
}
```

If you want **div#About** always stays at the bottom,change absolute to fixed

Comment: Next time, make an edit and strike your changes :) this is not what I want. I was looking for the footer to stay at the end of the page (not the screen) and `fixed` is for the screen, and `position: absolute;bottom: 0;` set the bottom of the `about` section to ~700px, no matter what size is the page

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you want.You have to choose between absolute and fixed,

Comment: then that's my fault, I didn't explain it well ;) run the rendering on the original code : http://jsfiddle.net/qe5Jg/1/, scroll down and keep in mind the space between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the rendering window then remove the image and compare the new space